# Easy Automatic Magento Stores DB + Files Linux Server Backup?

Tags: linux, magento

I have 20 magento stores on linux and I think it's the time to create some sort of backup plan, I would like some continuous (If possible!) or daily backup of everything I have researched for paid solution but nothing seems to fit all my requirements. Because I understand I need separate backup for files and separate for MySQL databases because they can be corrupted if just copied. What guys can you recommend something easy for backups and also to be able quickly recover for a live website if something does happens!

Comment: I think you should ask here : http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mysqldump you can either build a cronjob on your own that will simply make a mysqldump (please do not forget to use --single-transaction option).
Or have a look at this http://docs.hollandbackup.org/provider_configs/mysqldump.html or this (if you have high load during all the day) http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/

And for dump the file, I think a really simple shell script that will rsync your /var/www/MyAwesomeWebsite to your /home/backup/today and then tgz it will be enough.

I hope it helps,

Comment: I really like the percona xtrabackup seems like a top notch tool. Wondering if it works with percona database? I think about using percona server for database :)

Comment: Percona xtrabackup works with percona database but also with standard mysql database :).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all the 20 stores on one server? And you want to back them all up into 1 archive?

If not - I can recommend magento backup extension by Mageplace - it can be scheduled to backup magento files and DB and whatever else in Magento folder on daily basis keeping, let's say, 5 latest backups.

So if you have 20 separate stores you'll just need to set them all up once and have backups done  automatically.